# Forces involved when an elevator decellerates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When an elevator decelerates when it approaches the chosen floor (going upwards), the net force is downwards and that is why it decelerates. If the net force is downwards, then why does it not fall downwards? Why does it simply decelerate? Can someone please explain the forces involved in elevators in detail so that I can thoroughly perceive the forces behind it?

Comment: That’s like asking why a car doesn’t go backwards when braking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be assuming that velocity should be in the same direction as acceleration. But consider the case of an object tossed up from the surface of the earth. The only force acting on it (neglecting air resistance) is the downward force of gravity. Yet the object continues to move upward with gradually decreasing speed until it stops. In this case, as with the elevator, there is an initial velocity which must be overcome before the object stops.

If instead an object is released from a height with zero initial velocity, then both the force of gravity and the velocity of the object would be in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the elevator starts at ground and increase its velocity upto half way height. In that case, acceleration is in upward direction. In other words each passing moment, upward velocity is increasing. To explain more, if you take difference of velocity at $t$ second and $t+1$ second as $v_{t+1} - v_t$, this vector points upwards. So the direction of acceleration is upward and has a positive sign because it has same direction as that of velocity. $Deceleration$ term is used when magnitude of velocity is decreasing. It is nothing but just acceleration with negative sign.

Similarly when at some height midway if it starts to decrease its velocity, then $v_{t+1} - v_t$ has a negative sign because in the previous case, the upward direction had a positive sign. This means that the acceleration is in downward direction. But since it has now a negative sign while the direction of velocity is still positive (upward), it is called deceleration here.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

[image]

This might satisfy you!!... All the Best

Comment: Please type your questions instead of posting pictures of handwritten notes.